# Installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

My dev box is a Windows 7 machine and I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio.

When I run the installation SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe (downloaded from Microsoft [site](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593)), it complains with the following error message.

[image]

I do not have Visual Studio 2008 installed on my machine. I do have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and VS 2005 installed on my machine though.

Now, I downloaded Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and tried installing that, it came up with the following error message.

[image]

Any idea why it is complaining in the first place and pointers as to how to resolve it?

**UPDATE:** 
Apologies! I just double checked and found that there are a bunch of Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86.

Could this be the cause of issues?

I will uninstall these and see if that fixes my issue.

[image]

Comment: **Now, I downloaded Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and tried installing that**  If you don't have VS2008 installed that is the reason you got the error.  As for the error caused by the application you want to install I can't explain that.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks. Well, that is quite evident isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server installs a version of Visual Studio itself - rebadged as Business Intelligence Development Studio. Do you have a previous version of this installed?

Is your version of VS2010 fully up-to-date?

I vaguely recall I had this problem on a new development machine (VM) early this year. Unfortunately, I just rolled back the VM and installed SQL 2008 first before anything else. Not entirely helpful, I know.

Comment: CJM: No, I do not have a previous version of SQL Server installed.